# Rails text_field attribute ui-jq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add an attribute `ui-jq="tagsinput"` to the input field as follows

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'form-control', :ui => {:jq => 'tagsinput'}, value: @campaign.tag_list.join(",") %>
```

But i am getting the following output

```
<input type="text" id="campaign_tag_list" name="campaign[tag_list]" value="sadasasdasd" ui="{:jq=&gt;&quot;tagsinput&quot;}" class="form-control">
```

Even when i nest it inside the `:html` am still getting similar error.

Comment: `<%= f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'form-control', "ui-jq" => "tagsinput", value: @campaign.tag_list.join(",") %>` - have you tried this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get `ui-jq="tagsinput"`:

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, :class => 'form-control', "ui-jq" => "tagsinput", value: @campaign.tag_list.join(",") %>
```